# Как преобразовать GPS-координаты в формат float (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gps, exif

Написала код, который извлекает долготу и широту из exif-пакета Node.js. Необходимо преобразовать GPS-координаты в градусы формата float

```js
var ExifImage = require('exif').ExifImage;

try {
    new ExifImage({ image : 'myImage.jpg' }, function (error, exifData) {
        if (error)
            console.log('Error: '+error.message);
        else
            var gps = {
                latitude: exifData.gps.GPSLatitude,
                longtitude: exifData.gps.GPSLongitude
            };
            console.log(gps);
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
}
```

Comment: Преобразовывайте. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: в том, что не знаю как это делается